# Encapsulate several field at once in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, encapsulation

In visual studio you can set accessors by using the [encapsulate field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5adyhe9.aspx) refactoring operation on a declaration (Ctrl + E,R shortcut).

Is it possible to generate (using the default settings) the accessors of several field at once ?

Having :

```
private int one;
private int two;
//etc
```

and generating :

```
public int One
{
    get { return one; }
    set { one = value; }
}

public int Two
{
    get { return two; }
    set { two = value; }
}

//etc
```

without selecting each declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and i tried many things but then i found one good solution and it works as well.. I have tried just now in my visual studio 2010. It is very easy to create getter and setter by just one step using this add on..

Please refer below link:-
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AsEclipse.AsEclipseV210